# What are alternatives to Razl?

Tags: sitecore-client, razl

I want to compare two Sitecore databases. I know there is a tool named [Razl](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Razl), but it's not free.

What are alternatives?

The crazy idea is to serialize everything via Unicorn and then compare serialized items via something like WinMerge, but I'm afraid it won't be that convenient for this purpose.

Comment: Razl isn’t free but it’s cheap, and only a one off cost. You’ll save yourself a ton of hassle (and man hours that’ll cost more than the fee).

Answer (score 7):

One option could be Sitecore Sidekick:

- https://github.com/JeffDarchuk/SitecoreSidekick
- https://jeffdarchuk.com/2016/10/03/sitecore-sidekick/
- https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/Sitecore_Sidekick.aspx

It's free but I'm not sure about it's current status. It should be able to do a lot more than just compare, but it is one of it's features (Content Migrator).

[image]

Didn't use it myself yet, but might be worth looking into. And it's open source so if something is not working, you could contribute to a solution.

Comment: One thing that Sidekick does not have is syncing using History Engine. Razl has that  History Sync and I have currently set that up to sync on a History Engine sliding window every 1 hour to get the latest content from production to another Sitecore instance.
Obviously someone making a pull request into SideKick can make this whole thing available again.